# How to use TChartValueList in c++ builder

Tags: c++, builder

Anyone can help to check the code segment listed below which has error compiling when try to access element of TChartValueList, thanks.

```
((TCandleSeries *) chartInfo.area[index].series[SER_PR_PRICE])->OnGetPointerStyle = &SeriesCandleGetPointerStyle;

TSeriesPointerStyle _fastcall TForm1::SeriesCandleGetPointerStyle(TChartSeries *Sender, int ValueIndex)
{

TCandleSeries               *series;

gSeries = findSeries(AREA_TYPE_PRICE, SER_PR_PRICE);
if (gSeries != NULL)
{
    series = (TCandleSeries *) gSeries;

    series->HighLowPen->Color = series->DownCloseColor;

    if (ValueIndex > 0)
    {
        if (series->CloseValues[ValueIndex] >= series->OpenValues[ValueIndex])
            *****^^^^^^^^^^ [BCC32 Error] E2093 'operator>=' not implemented in type 'TChartValueList' for arguments of the same type*****
            series->HighLowPen->Color = series->UpCloseColor;
    }
}

return psRectangle;
}
```

Comment: What is the compiling error that you have?

Comment: [BCC32 Error] E2093 'operator>=' not implemented in type 'TChartValueList' for arguments of the same type

Comment: Basically, I have no idea how to access element in TChartValueList.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://www.teechart.net/docs/ (Tutorials > Working with Series > Accessing Series values) ?